# QTableView / QTableWidget: Stretch Last Column using Qt Designer

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer, pyqt5

I am trying to stretch the last header of my QTableView / QTableWidget in PyQt. Multiple questions have been asked about this topic already by hard coding the value into the file such as:

[Qt table last column not stretching to fill in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906708/qt-table-last-column-not-stretching-to-fill-in-parent)

[How to stretch QTableView last column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070340/how-to-stretch-qtableview-last-column-header)

But how can this be achieved from the Qt Designer?

[image: Before]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Qt Designer, Select the QTableWidget / QTableView and navigate to the Property Editor. Here, scroll down to the 'Header section' and enable **horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection**.

[image: Qt Designer Property Box]
[image: Qt After stretch]

Comment: Is it possible to make all columns stretch equally from the designer?