# QTableView / QTableWidget: Stretch Last Column

Tags: qt, qml, qtableview, qheaderview

How to stretch the last column of a TableView in qml?

In C++ with Qt framework it is possible to use **setStretchLastSection** from **QHeaderView** but is there a way to do it in qml?

EDIT: To be more specific: On the screenshot below, I want the three column to fill the entire width of the TableView, in order to get rid that "ghost" 4th column.

Edit2:

I wanted to do something like that:

```
TableView{
  model: ListModel{
    ListElement {
      name: "Apple"
      cost: 2.45
    }
    ListElement {
      name: "Orange"
      cost: 3.25
    }
    ListElement {
      name: "Banana"
      cost: 1.95
    }
  }

  TableViewColumn{
    role: "name"
    title: "Name"
  }
  TableViewColumn{
    role: "cost"
    title: "Cost"
  }
  Component.onCompleted: stretchLastSection /*<-----/*
}
```

But the way to do it for now seems to be by calculating the width of TableViewColumn as @folibis said.

[image]

Some related topic with QtDesigner and Qt framework:

[QTableView / QTableWidget: Stretch Last Column using Qt Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29855712/qtableview-qtablewidget-stretch-last-column-using-qt-designer)

[Qt table last column not stretching to fill in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906708/qt-table-last-column-not-stretching-to-fill-in-parent)

[How to stretch QTableView last column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26070340/how-to-stretch-qtableview-last-column-header)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: As said above it is hard to answer a question without details, [mcve] etc. Anyway, check the [TableView.columnWidthProvider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#columnWidthProvider-prop) property that holds a function that returns the widths of columns. You can just calculate that: `TableView.width` - Σ (all columns widths) - the last one.